# Linking one-to-many (Employee to Salary History) lists in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, one-to-many

Here is my issue:

[Edit]: Alright, this is almost turning into a separate question at this point...my apologies. To cut right to the chase, here is my business requirement. I have an Employee record (an item in a list) that contains a Salary field. I need to be able to view a report of the Employee's salary history.

That's it. In my mind (which is definitely coming from a SQL/database background) this meant a one-to-many table (one Employee with many Salaries). Turns out this is not so simple in SharePoint since I would have to filter the Salary field to only display Salaries from the SalaryHistory list for a given Employee.

My new-ish question is what's the best way to do this? Is it possible to use only an Employee list with a Salary field and then somehow view or display the history of that particular Salary field? For example, if the Salary was changed from 50,000 to 60,000 for Employee 00001, can I view a report/page of some sort that shows the history of this Salary field?

[/Edit]

I want to convert an existing MS Access/VBA legacy system to SharePoint 2010. The existing MS Access system is fairly simple: a database of Employees, with typical Employee information, including a Salary History. The one issue I am having trouble with is that an Employee has not only a Salary, but a Salary History. What this means is that a supervisor should be able to view an Employee's Salary History, and not just the current salary of the Employee.

In my mind, this is a one-to-many relationship: an Employee table linked to a Salary History table (the one-to-many is that an Employee can have many Salaries over a period of time).

What's the best way to implement this in SharePoint? I have tried using InfoPath as well as some customized code, but I can't seem to get it correct. In my mind, this is a relatively simple concept, but I'm having trouble taking it from concept to a concrete SharePoint solution.

Any ideas or advice?

Thanks,

Glen

Comment: I will add that I did post this on SharePoint stackexchange as well. I don't know if this is considered bad etiquette or not (I'm hoping it's not). In my mind, this solution may have some code/programming in it, so I posted it here as well. I have no problem removing this question from stackoverflow if this is considered bad form.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of setup works quite well in SharePoint. The only real basic requirement is your relationships need to be a "basic" setup.

The, the relationships between two tables need two things:

a) You use a standard auto number primary key for the parent table.

b) You use a standard long number column for the child table.

Turns out the above are the basic default for Access anyway. So the first tip/trick is to ensure you get your relationship setup correctly. **IF** you do this correct then you can up-size and send the tables up to SharePoint and your relational data WILL GO UP INTACT.

Now that SharePoint supports the relational database feature of cascade delete (and delete restrict), then if you delete a parent record, then the child records in child tables will cascade delete for you.

And keep in mind that during an up load, that "meaningless" PK number id may be changed (and that means a cascade update of the child FK (foreign keys) can also occur.

Because your existing relationships lily will not go up correct, then you best "delete" the relationships, and re-create them.

Also don't forget to check the option in Access to use the "new" cache format. The one I am talking about is this one:

[image]

The results of this setup are nothing short of amazing since then your application will now operate in "off line" dis connected mode. That means if you pull your network plug even with multiple users all connected to this database, they all can keep working.  They all have a local high speed cache (this setup can often run circles around sql server). So if you run a report on 10,000 record table, you don't need any bandwidth!

And when the internet connection is restored or you get back from the field to a coffee shop with Wi-Fi then the data will sync for you (data syncs between all connected users in real time). And this setup in general requires ZERO changes to your existing VBA code.  (there is one exception in which code needs to be changed).

Now, the next issue/part is how to setup the relationships so they go up to SharePoint. I explain the steps in the following video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wdjYIby_b0&list=PL27E956A1537FE1C5&index=2&feature=plpp_video

Note in the above this quite much means you have to use the relationships wizard, and not the relationship design window to correctly setup these relationships. If you do the above, then an up-size to SharePoint will thus send up tables and will keep the relations intact on SharePoint.

edit: Also, in the above video, I publish the database to SharePoint because I had Access Web Services available. You  do NOT need to publish, but you can use the Database Tools tab and use the SharePoint button.
[image]

Comment: Albert, first of all, thank you for your *very* thorough answer. I almost hate to say this, and perhaps I should have elaborated in my original question, I don't have the original Access database application. What I have is a screenshot from the client's database application and a request to "make something like this" in a vague kind of way -- that's not to say that I can't get a copy of it and go with what you suggested.

Thanks for your help.

I'd like to mark it as "accepted" for being so good, but I'm not sure if it would be entirely accurate.